# Determine types from a variadic function's arguments in C

Tags: printf, variadic-functions

I'd like a step by step explanation on how to parse the arguments of a variadic function
so that when calling `va_arg(ap, TYPE);` I pass the correct data TYPE of the argument being passed.

Currently I'm trying to code `printf`.
I am only **looking for an explanation** preferably **with simple examples** but **not the solution** to `printf` since I want to solve it myself.

Here are three examples which look like what I am looking for:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689228/3206885
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5551632/3206885
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1722238/3206885

I know the basics of what `typedef`, `struct`, `enum` and `union` do but can't figure out some practical application cases like the examples in the links.

What do they really mean? I can't wrap my brain around how they work.
How can I pass the data type from a union to `va_arg` like in the links examples? How does it match?
with a modifier like `%d`, `%i` ... or the data type of a parameter?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "my.h"

typedef struct s_flist
{
    char c;
    (*f)();
}              t_flist;

int     my_printf(char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int     i;
    int     j;
    int     result;
    int     arg_count;
    char    *cur_arg = format;
    char    *types;
    t_flist flist[] = 
    {
        { 's',  &my_putstr  },
        { 'i',  &my_put_nbr },
        { 'd',  &my_put_nbr }
    };

    i = 0;
    result = 0;
    types = (char*)malloc( sizeof(*format) * (my_strlen(format) / 2 + 1) );
    fparser(types, format);
    arg_count = my_strlen(types);

    while (format[i])
    {
        if (format[i] == '%' && format[i + 1])
        {
            i++;
            if (format[i] == '%')
                result += my_putchar(format[i]);
            else
            {
                j = 0;
                va_start(ap, format);
                while (flist[j].c)
                {
                    if (format[i] == flist[j].c)
                        result += flist[i].f(va_arg(ap, flist[i].DATA_TYPE??));
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        result += my_putchar(format[i]);
        i++;
    }

    va_end(ap);
    return (result);
}

char    *fparser(char *types, char *str)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] == '%' && str[i + 1] &&
            str[i + 1] != '%' && str[i + 1] != ' ')
        {
            i++;
            types[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    types[j] = '\0';
    return (types);
}
```

Comment: yesss ft_printf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get actual type information from `va_list`. You can get what you're looking for from `format`. What it seems you're not expecting is: none of the arguments *know* what the actual types are, but `format` represents the caller's idea of what the types *should* be. (Perhaps a further hint: what would the *actual* `printf` do if a caller gave it format specifiers that didn't match the varargs passed in? Would it notice?)

Your code would have to parse the format string for "%" format specifiers, and use those specifiers to branch into reading the `va_list` with specific hardcoded types. For example, (pseudocode) `if (fspec was "%s") { char* str = va_arg(ap, char*); print out str; }`. Not giving more detail because you explicitly said you didn't want a complete solution.

---

You will never have a *type* as a piece of runtime data that you can pass to `va_arg` as a value. The second argument to `va_arg` must be a literal, hardcoded specification referring to a known type at compile time. (Note that `va_arg` is a macro that gets expanded at compile time, not a function that gets executed at runtime - you couldn't have a function taking a type as an argument.)

A couple of your links suggest keeping track of types via an enum, but this is only for the benefit of your own code being able to branch based on that information; it is still not something that can be passed to `va_arg`. You have to have separate pieces of code saying literally `va_arg(ap, int)` and `va_arg(ap, char*)` so there's no way to avoid a `switch` or a chain of `if`s.

The solution you want to make, using the unions and structs, would start from something like this:

```
typedef union {
  int i;
  char *s;
} PRINTABLE_THING;

int print_integer(PRINTABLE_THING pt) {
  // format and print pt.i
}
int print_string(PRINTABLE_THING pt) {
  // format and print pt.s
}
```

The two specialized functions would work fine on their own by taking explicit `int` or `char*` params; the reason we make the union is to enable the functions to formally take the same type of parameter, so that they have the same signature, so that we can define a single type that means *pointer to that kind of function*:

```
typedef int (*print_printable_thing)(PRINTABLE_THING);
```

Now your code can have an array of function pointers of type `print_printable_thing`, or an array of structs that have `print_printable_thing` as one of the structs' fields:

```
typedef struct {
  char format_char;
  print_printable_thing printing_function;
} FORMAT_CHAR_AND_PRINTING_FUNCTION_PAIRING;

FORMAT_CHAR_AND_PRINTING_FUNCTION_PAIRING formatters[] = {
  { 'd', print_integer },
  { 's', print_string }
};
int formatter_count = sizeof(formatters) / sizeof(FORMAT_CHAR_AND_PRINTING_FUNCTION_PAIRING);
```

(Yes, the names are all intentionally super verbose. You'd probably want shorter ones in the real program, or even anonymous types where appropriate.)

Now you can use that array to select the correct formatter at runtime:

```
for (int i = 0; i < formatter_count; i++)
  if (current_format_char == formatters[i].format_char)
    result += formatters[i].printing_function(current_printable_thing);
```

But the process of getting the correct thing into `current_printable_thing` is still going to involve branching to get to a `va_arg(ap, ...)` with the correct hardcoded type. Once you've written it, you may find yourself deciding that you didn't actually need the union nor the array of structs.

Comment: Oh well I've tried a specifier with the wrong type and and error pops when I try to compile of course. I know that %s should be a string, $d an int and so on but how can I then associate the specifier with a type dynamically into va_arg is a mystery.

Comment: Oh, if your compiler was able to catch `printf("%s", 0.1)`, that's only because it's smart and treats `printf` as a special name. Normally, this isn't the kind of thing that can get caught at compile time (nor at run time). Edited the answer to give another hint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had already done all what you are hinting me to do (see my code on the post). The actual point on which I was stuck was: I know the type to pass to va_arg with %s, %i ...etc, I am looking for how to to this without a "forest of if" or a switch/case by using an array of function pointer. Function who can print a char, print a string, print a number and all the others types printf can do.

Comment: I had already figured out how to parse the format string and pass the corresponding type to va_arg, see my code on the post. I am now searching to do this with an array of function pointer (my_putchar, my_putstr, my_put_number ...). I'm looking for a way to do it. I think[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27483965/3206885) answer and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5551632/3206885) + [this last one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1722238/3206885) are what I need but don't fully understand the use of a struct containing an enum and a union. I hope you understand where I am right now.

Comment: My fault for no understanding your question completely at first. Updated answer again.

Comment: You are correct, what I really was looking for was an elegent way to call `va_arg(ap, ...)` with the _type_. Now I know it must be hardcoded, no other way around it. I had all the right ideas... makes me feel better for all the time spent thinking harder and harder to come up with a better solution but C is quite strict. Thanks you very much, you're awesome !

Comment: I have found [something interesting](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11c.html) concerning va_arg. It will never receive a second argument of type char, short int, or float. It's worth mentioning for future people who will have the same kind of project.